# Meteor doesn't work after install on Windows 10

Tags: meteor, npm

After downloading and running the Meteor Installer (v1.4 - current) It says meteor is installed but the meteor command is still not recognised. I have restarted, and also tried installing via npm which resulted in an error from another package (fibers).

It seems like it should just work, and I'm not sure why it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Running the command `meteor` in any command prompt window will complete the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Meteor Installation path in your PATH Environment Variable

Meteor Installation Directory will be(default)

> c:\Users\\AppData\Local.meteor

So Add

> c:\Users\\AppData\Local.meteor

to your PATH then restart command prompt try meteor